# Is saying 'sarcastic humour' proper? Example: "Your humour isn't sarcastic enough."

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-request, expressions

For example:

> My humour isn't sarcastic enough.

I haven't seen its use in anywhere before. Is it okay to use? If not then what can be a proper way to say it?

Comment: Google Ngram search **[result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humour+is+sarcastic%2C+humour+is+sarcastic%2C+sarcastic+humor%2C+sarcastic+humour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csarcastic%20humor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csarcastic%20humour%3B%2Cc0)**.

Comment: I'm not very sure but perhaps it's less and less popular (as shown in CopperKettle's) because we also have other words which may convey related meanings, such as *mockery*, *parody*, or *burlesque*. -- Also notes that *sarcastic N* and *N isn't sarcastic (enough)*, though look similar, are not quite the same, Some adjectives can be used in both places; others seem to be primarily used in one position rather than the other.

Comment: a more colloquial word would be sassy

Answer (score 3):

*Sarcastic* is an adjective so yes, it's fine, but we generally don't discuss someone's "humour" unless it's a comedy act, e.g., "I really enjoy George Carlin's humour." For non-comedians, we'd say "your *sense of* humour is really sarcastic."

(I'm not sure when I'd ever tell someone they're not sufficiently sarcastic. Does the world need more sarcasm?)

Comment: I wondered what you wondered. _Your humour isn't sarcastic enough_ sounds a bit sarcastic to me. :^)